# app pings server multiple time on sleep

Tags: android, multithreading, gps

I wrote an app that is supposed to get GPS coordinates of the user and then transmit the coords to our database and it seems to be working fine until the device goes to sleep then it sends the data multiple times.

I am not very good when it comes to multiple threads and synchronicity and that may be the problem here are the code snippets I found and used to upload the data via a url

When it tried to pull just the parts out that did the actual internet connection and opening of the url the code failed so I kept it in its original form.

```
private void loadGPS(String urlStr) {
    final String url = urlStr;

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = openHttpConnection(url);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlStr) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int resCode = -1;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Http URL");
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

What I need help with is to eliminate the double or triple sending of the data it seems like each time the app goes into a sleep mode another sequence is begun and it is independent of the original so as the new sequence transmits its data the prior sequence is doing the same and that is why I get double entries triple if it falls asleep again
The app is set to gather GPS info every 30 seconds and transmit it independent of user interaction
Here is some output showing the single data and then having the double entries show up. This start right after the app goes into sleep mode

```
3 -121.9721396100 37.7565088200 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721402400 37.7565188400 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721407600 37.7565261900 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721426800 37.7565248100 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721358700 37.7565181200 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721341300 37.7565172300 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721293900 37.7565175200 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721285400 37.7565220300 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721282700 37.7565201000 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721282700 37.7565201000 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721114200 37.7565106500 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721114200 37.7565106500 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721175200 37.7565121300 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 -121.9721175200 37.7565121300 0000-00-00 00:00:00





   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setGUI();
}

private void setGUI() {
    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    textSpeed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSpeed);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30000    ,0,ll);

}

private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();
            long pDate = location.getTime();
            double pSpeed = location.getSpeed();
            double pBearing = location.getBearing();
            int wardid = 3;
/*

    Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
    G   Era designator  Text    AD
    y   Year    Year    1996; 96
    Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
    M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
    w   Week in year    Number  27
    W   Week in month   Number  2
    D   Day in year     Number  189
    d   Day in month    Number  10
    F   Day of week in month    Number  2
    E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
    u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
    a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
    H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
    k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
    K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
    h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
    m   Minute in hour  Number  30
    s   Second in minute    Number  55
    S   Millisecond     Number  978
    z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
    Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
    X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00

 */


            textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));


            SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("E, MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
            Date resultdate = new Date (pDate);
            textDate.setText(sdf.format(resultdate));
            textSpeed.setText(Double.toString(pSpeed));

            String GPSurl = null;
            GPSurl = new String("http://www.mysiteinformation.com/GPSload.php?WARDID=" + wardid + "&LAT=" + Double.toString(pLat) + "&LONG=" + Double.toString(pLong) + "&TIME=" + sdf.format(resultdate));
            //Toast.makeText(this, GPSurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 //===================
            loadGPS(GPSurl);
//===================
```

Comment: Where do you call `loadGPS` from?

Comment: I will add that snippet as well